# How to Write Case Statement Using sys.time_zone_info

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help in writing a Case statement to get the 'US Eastern Standard Time' from the sys.time_zone_info system view in SQL Server. There is an error in the Select statement and cannot figure out where. The CN.CreateDate is currently in UTC time and need to convert to EST taking into account Daylight Savings time.

```
select 
CN.CreateDate
,case when (SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info TZI WHERE    
TZI.name = 'US Eastern Standard Time'
        AND ISNULL(TZI.is_currently_dst,0)=0) 
        THEN DATEADD(hour, -5,CN.CreateDate) 
        ELSE DATEADD(hour, -4,CN.CreateDate) 
        END AS CreateDateEST
from MC_CDCPContactNotes CN
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have a boolean expression in your `WHEN`, just a subquery. Should it be `WHEN {Sub Query} = '<Literal Value>'`? `WHEN {Sub Query} IS NULL`? Something else?

Comment: Your case expression is only half there. It would make it more obvious if you formatted your subquery better.

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is built into SQL Server with [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), there's no need to re-invent the wheel here. Only thing to note is that you may need to convert to UTC then to your required zone first, e.g.

```
WITH MC_CDCPContactNotes AS 
(   SELECT  t.CreateDate
    FROM (VALUES (('20221225 00:00'), ('20220625 00:00')) AS t (CreateDate)
)
SELECT  CN.CreateDate,
        EasternTime = cn.CreateDate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE  'US Eastern Standard Time'
FROM    MC_CDCPContactNotes CN;
```

Which gives:

| CreateDate | EasternTime |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-25 | 2022-12-24 19:00:00 -05:00 |
| 2022-06-25 | 2022-06-24 20:00:00 -04:00 |

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3c-A8KEb)**

Comment: Is there a way to run this query without hard coding dates and still converts to EST while taking DST into account?

Comment: The hard coded values are just the sample data I was using as I don't have access to your data, you can do this with any date column. If it simplifies things I've done a new fiddle with an actual table for sample data rather than using a CTE for the sample data - https://dbfiddle.uk/13Pg52E7

Comment: To be explicit `at time zone` takes DST into account. Try it with your own data to convince yourself.

Comment: Wow this did the trick and so easy, Thank You:                                                
EasternTime = cn.CreateDate AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE  'US Eastern Standard Time'

Answer (score 0):

Just to fix your query:

```
select 
  CN.CreateDate
  ,case when (SELECT 
                 count(*) 
                 FROM sys.time_zone_info TZI 
                 WHERE TZI.name = 'US Eastern Standard Time'
                 AND ISNULL(TZI.is_currently_dst,0)=0) = 1 
    THEN DATEADD(hour, -5,CN.CreateDate) 
    ELSE DATEADD(hour, -4,CN.CreateDate) 
    END AS CreateDateEST
 from MC_CDCPContactNotes CN
```

But I would rewrite it like:

```
select 
  CN.CreateDate
  ,dateadd(hour,-5+ISNULL(TZI.is_currently_dst,0),CN.CreateDate) as CreateDateEst 
from MC_CDCPContactNotes CN
join sys.time_zone_info TZI 
    on TZI.name = 'US Eastern Standard Time'
```

Comment: So it looks like this query example will not take into account Daylight Savings Time. If the date is 10/31/2022 it will still result in -5 hours, since 10/31/22 is DST and should be -4 hours.

Comment: The problem with this query, and the original one in the question is that `is_currently_dst` is irrelevant to `CreateDate` - you need to know if it was DST at the point in time of `CreateDate` ,which you can't establish using `sys.time_zone_info` alone. This answer successfully rewrites the original query in a better format, but unfortunately the entire premise was flawed from the outset